# What's the maximum number of SSL certificate can I create on IIS 8 per site?

Tags: c#, iis, ssl, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to create a site builder which will be a single web application hosted under one site on IIS 8.

It will accept multiple domains (actually it accepts all connections and then use domain names to decide whether it is a hosted customer's website).

Now I'm having concerns here that:  because many customers' websites will be eCommerce enabled, so they will be asking for installing SSL for their website --  because now IIS 8 allows "Server Name Indication" on hostname, so literally I can solve this by adding different hostnames onto this single site using my code (C#)

However question here is if I have 100+ customers using the single web application, i.e. this web application will work as if 100+ sites on IIS, how many certificates can I install on the single site?  will there be a potential huge problem (security/performance etc.)?

Many thanks!

Comment: There will be no hard limit, as certificates are not of the same size. Http.sys should be smart enough to cache certs and remove them from cache to avoid memory issue. But only testing can give you confidence.

Comment: that's great thanks - in that case I'll proceed the coding and test the load before implement it as solutions to our project. cheers

Comment: i am also curious ...what is it ?